# How can I improve the quality of more generic adwords keywords?

Tags: advertising, google-ads, ctr

I'm looking to improve the quality on some of my more generic keywords. 50% of my traffic comes from two keywords: "Bokförignsprogram" (accounting software) and "faktureringsprogram" (invoicing software). My ads relevance and expected CTR is only average but I wish to be more than average! ;)

With expected CTR, I understand that is only trial and error, but how could I make the ad for the exact match [bokföringsprogram], more relevant, other than using that exact phrase in my ad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tricks that I have learned to increase click through rate and AdWords quality score:

- Use the keyword in your ad. This gets an instance of bold text into the ad which catches the eye more easily
- Use numbers instead of superlatives.   People get turned off by "Best accounting software" but might be more receptive too "80% more usable" or "Tracking 1 billion dollars in companies' assets".
- Use a "call to action".   People are more likely to take the action you want them to perform on your site, if you mention that action in your ad.   Something like "download the free trial" or "buy today 20% off".
- Improve the relevance of your landing page.   Use the keywords on it as well.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer that Stephen provided - remember to keep the relevancy equal across the route that search visitor uses.

For instance, they type in 'double glazing company in London'

They see an Ad with title: 'Highly Recommended Double Glazing Business in London"

The description also contains London, then they need to land on a page that is all about Installing Double Glazing in Greater London, throughout London.

That keeps the relevancy high and ECTR relatively high.